# Scraping <a> tag links in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to get all the links for each storm's page in 1998 (link to list of storms below)
https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/archive/1998/1998archive.shtml

```
library(stringr)
storm_html_link <- "https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/archive/1998/1998ALEXadv.html"
storm_html <- paste(readLines(storm_html_link), collapse="\n")
storm_matched <- str_match_all(storm_html, "<a href=\"(.*?)\"")
print(storm_matched[[1]][,2])
```

The code above extracts the links on a storm's page, and I am trying to do this for every storm on the NHC website. For every storm in a year not in 1998, storm_matched contains the correct links for each storm's individual html page, but I just cannot populate storm_matched with anything for any storm in 1998.

Could anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: to scrap the website, use `rvest package`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(stringi)

site_1998 <- read_html("https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/archive/1998/1998archive.shtml") #set site
storms1998 <- site_1998 %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attr('href') %>% #at this point we have all htmls on the page
  .[which(stri_detect_regex(.,"1998"))] #keep only htmls with 1998 in the URL (leaves you with the links you want)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work for me.  If you want to extract data from link s on a page, try it this way.

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

URL <- "https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/archive/1998/1998ALEXadv.html"

pg <- read_html(URL)

all_links <- html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "a"), "href")
```